# XSL concatenate attributes in for each

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have xml which looks like this:

```
<field index="1" name="my_field_1" type="String">
<value>Value of Field 1</value>
</field>

<field index="2" name="my_field_2" type="String">
<value>Value of Field 2</value>
</field>

<field index="3" name="my_field_3" type="String">
<value>Value of Field 3</value>
</field>
```

Later in for each I iterate over those fields and I try to take name of field (which is same) and concatenate it with index attribute(which depends on number of elements which may vary).

I tried this (I put apostrophe in variable because I was not sure how to escape it).

```
<xsl:variable name="currentIndex" select="@index"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="apostrof">'</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="concat(
'//field[@name=',
$apostrof,
'sar_account_entrepreneur_name_',
@index,
$apostrof,
']/value')"/>
```

Problem is that this instead of select value it outputs literally just the string my_field_1 for example.
Output should be Value of Field 1, Value of Field 2 etc. What i need instead is to dynamicly concate name attribute with index attribute.

Comment: I think it was helpful if you gave an example of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: I updated xml to this:
<field index="1" name="my_field_1" type="String">
<value>Value of Field 1</value>
</field>

<field index="2" name="my_field_2" type="String">
<value>Value of Field 2</value>
</field>

so output would be 

Value of Field 1, Value of Field 2 etc

Comment: Alright, I think I got it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was rather simple:

This code takes index attr and concated it to name.

Answer (score 0):

The following transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="field">
            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

applied to this input

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
<field index="1" name="my_field_1" type="String">
    <value>Value of Field 1</value>
</field>

<field index="2" name="my_field_2" type="String">
    <value>Value of Field 2</value>
</field>

<field index="3" name="my_field_3" type="String">
    <value>Value of Field 3</value>
</field>
</root>
```

produces the desired output of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
Value of Field 1Value of Field 2Value of Field 3
```

I hope this helps. Otherwise give me a hint in a comment.

Comment: HI @heilsnoppe I need to be more clearler I need to use index  and join it with name of field. Because there are more fields and I am interested only in few of them. There fore in xsl I want to use write names of all fields and add index to them. 

Index is used because xml is generaqted automaticly and index can have value from 0 to n. If that make sense.

Comment: Maybe you can update your example so that it precisely reflects your input and your desired output?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear I found answer I will update the question and I will add the answer.